# apply closure to an arbitrary object in groovy

Tags: groovy, gradle, closures

In gradle there are places where you can pass a closure to an object itself in a builder style like so:

```
// ant is a property. an object.
ant {
    // do funky builder stuff
}
```

How can you create your own custom code to apply closures to objects? is there a method that i need to override in order to support this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could override the `call` operator. Groovy allows you to not place round braces around the closure argument.

```
class A {
  def call(Closure cl) {
    print(cl())
  }
}
def a = new A();
a {
    "hello"
}
```

Prints hello.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the way seagull mentioned:

Using a method that takes a closure:

```
class MyClass { 
  def ant (c) {
    c.call()
  }
}

def m = new MyClass()
m.ant { 
  println "hello"
}
```

Other one, using method missing, which gives more flexibility in terms of name of the method that takes a closure (`ant` in your case):

```
class A {
     def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        if (name == "ant") {
            // do somehting with closure
            args.first().call()
        }
    }
}

def a = new A()

a.ant { println "hello"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

```
Object.tap {} 
Object.with {}
```